# Set selected item in dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to set the selected item of my dropdown-menu in jquery but I can't make it work.

My dropdown code looks as follows:

```
<button type="button" id="aktiv" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Aktiv <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Aktiv</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Inaktiv</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the jquery code you've tried?

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://codeply.com/go/LDZSuGgQYO, or to preselect an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function can be used to set the text of the menu. It also sets the value of the button element so you can retrieve it using `$('#aktiv').val()`.

```
function setAktivMenu(text) {
    $('#aktiv').val(text).html(function(i, html) {
        return text + html.slice(html.indexOf(' <'));
    });
}
```

You can call the function to set the menu text like this:

```
setAktivMenu('Inaktiv');
```

You can also set up an event handler for the menu options so they cause the menu text to change when they are clicked:

```
$('#aktiv + .dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li>a', function() {
    setAktivMenu($(this).text());
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9aeahLj/3/)

Comment: hmmm .. im not sure what that does but it does not seem to be able to set the selected item (either Aktiv or Inaktiv). I want to SET it after i receive data from my web-service. 

Just like setting input: $('#myInput').val("Aktiv")

Of course that does not work for dropdown-menu but you get the point :)

Comment: @DTH - My original answer showed how to change the menu text when a menu option was clicked. I have updated my answer to show how that code can be pulled out into a function that allows you to set the menu text.

Comment: I will try it out later it looks promissing

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused at your 'dropdown menu'. Normally someone would be made in this fashion...

```
<select class="dropdown-menu">
    <option value="Aktiv"> Aktiv </option>
    <option value="Inaktiv"> Inaktiv </option>
</select>
```

If this was the type of dropdown menu you were aiming for you could set the selected value using...

```
$(".dropdown-menu").val("Aktiv");
```